# Centering images and text in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been having some trouble centering some items on my [website](http://actionscript.no/passwords). 
The items in question are in the passphrase generator (images and text elements in the dark box). I have tried the usual margin:auto, all the different display properties, text-align, align-self, align-content and align-items. None worked.

I was also wondering if anyone knew how we could get the text element under our images isntead of to the right, [this is the code used for the generator](http://actionscript.no/passphrase.js).

All help is appreciated

Comment: What you want to center?

Comment: The images and text elements in the dark box in the passphrase generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `p` tag is a block element, so the default width is 100%. This is why you have one element per line

```
#passphraseBilder {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#passphraseBilder p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Turn the `p` tag into inline or inline-block, and it will work ;-)

Have a look to the difference between block and inline: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: And remove the display: -webkit-box;

Comment: This worked, thank you! Any idea what i can do to get the text underneath the images aswell?

Comment: Put your image and text in a container (a div), put your div in Inline display, and on your div, the image has to be in "block" and text too.
Don't forget to check this answer if it helped you :-)

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The images and text now go vertically and the container background is not covering the elements.

Comment: Can you send a fiddle?

Comment: Not sure how I would make it into a fiddle since i use stored images etc. But  http://actionscript.no/passwords is updated with the suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#passphraseBilder {
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
}
```

Note: I have just added the properties which you should add or overwrite. Existing properties has to be there.